# Finding a limit algebraically

Tags: calculus

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }{ \frac { 1 }{\tan\theta -1 } -\frac { 2 }{ \tan {^ 2\theta -1 }  } } $$

Steps I took:

$$\begin{align}\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }{ (\frac { 1 }{ \tan\theta -1 } -\frac { 2 }{ \sec^{ 2 }\theta  } ) } &=(\frac { 1 }{ \frac { \sin\theta  }{ \cos\theta  } -\frac { \cos\theta  }{ \cos\theta  }  } -\frac { 2 }{ \frac { 1 }{ \cos^{ 2 }\theta  }  } )\\&=\frac { 1 }{ \frac { \sin\theta -\cos\theta  }{ \cos\theta  }  } -\frac { 2\cos^{ 2 }\theta  }{ 1 } \\&=\frac { \cos\theta  }{ \sin\theta -cos\theta  } -\frac { 2\cos^{ 2 }\theta  }{ 1 } \\&=\frac { \cos\theta  }{ \sin\theta -\cos\theta  } -\frac { 2\cos^{ 2 }\theta  }{ 1 } \cdot \frac { (\sin\theta -\cos\theta ) }{ (\sin\theta -\cos\theta ) } \\&=\frac { \cos\theta -2\cos^{ 2 }\theta (\sin\theta -\cos\theta ) }{ \sin\theta -\cos\theta  } \\&=\end{align}$$

I am now stuck and see no way to go any further.

Please provide a hint so that I can arrive at the correct solution by myself (hopefully).

Comment: Write your expression with a common denominator of $\tan^2\theta - 1$. You'll find it becomes rather nice.

Comment: *Lots* of spoon-feeding going on in these answers! And yet nobody took the time to demonstrate the manipulation of the L.H.S...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting step is where you went wrong: 
$$
\tan^2 \theta -1 \neq \sec^2 \theta \\
\tan^2 \theta +1 = \sec^2 \theta $$

Note that 
$$\frac{1}{\tan \theta -1} - \frac{2}{\tan^2 \theta -1}
= \frac{\tan \theta +1-2}{\tan^2 \theta -1}
=\frac{\tan \theta -1}{\tan^2 \theta -1} = 
\frac{1}{\tan \theta +1}
$$

How does this behave when $\tan \theta$ becomes large?

Comment: I should have realized that the denominator on the RHS is a difference of squares... I am going to work with this new realization and see where it gets me. I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try using the equality

$$\frac{1}{\tan\theta -1}-\frac{2}{\tan^2\theta -1}=\frac{1}{1+\tan\theta}$$

and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{(\tan \theta + 1)}{(\tan \theta -1)(\tan \theta + 1)} - \frac{2}{\tan^2\theta - 1} &= \lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan \theta  + 1 - 2}{\tan^2\theta - 1} \\&= \lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan \theta   - 1}{\tan^2\theta - 1} \\&= \lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\tan \theta  + 1}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

it is equivalent to $\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)}$

Answer (score 0):

After adding these two fractions you will notice that a lot of things reduce.
$$\frac{1}{\tan \theta - 1} - \frac{2}{\tan^2 \theta - 1} = \frac{\tan \theta + 1 - 2}{\tan^2 \theta - 1} = \frac{1}{\tan \theta + 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }{ (\frac { 1 }{ tan\theta -1 } -\frac { 2 }{ sec^{ 2 }\theta  } )} = \lim_{\theta \rightarrow \frac {\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\tan\theta+1} = \frac12$